# PHP selecting from database

Tags: php, database, arrays, select

I'm having trouble selecting data from inside one of the tables in the database.

I'm trying to display a user's profile when their name is clicked on.

```
<?php
    $view = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from users where id=$view"));
    if (empty ($view[id])) {
    print "No such user.";
    exit;
    }
    print "<center><b><u>$view[user]</b></u> ($view[id])</center><br>";
    print "Rank: $view[rank]<br>";
?>
```

The link they will click is:

```
viewpage.php?page_id=4&view=....
```

I can't get this to work.

Comment: By using `view=....`; you mean that the name itself is `....`?

Comment: where do you expect that initial $view to come from?  You should be sanitizing the argument and using SQL placeholders rather than direct interpolation to prevent against SQL Injection.

Comment: Have you enabled `error_reporting(E_ALL)`? What does `mysql_error()` say? What's the database structure? What's its table content? Have you tried the query in PhpMyAdmin etc?

Comment: the "..." is where the user id will be..      

When i add this code and click the user, all i see is "No such user"

Nothing else

Comment: i see something weird in ("select * from users where id = $view"), i think you must change $view with a right parameter, maybe something like this : $val = $_GET['view']; and in sql query like this : ("select * from users where id = $val")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
   $id=$_GET["view"];
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id");
   if($query)
   {
      echo '<table>';
      echo '<tr><th>Name</th><th>ID</th><th>Something Else</th></tr>';
      while($view = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
      {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>'.$view['Name'].'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$view['id'].'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$view['some other variable in your data'].'</td>';
         echo '</tr>'; //This one goes after you've echoed all the data for one user.
      }
      echo '</table>';
   } else {
      echo 'no user found';
   }

 ?>
```